# Residue theorem in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

Residue theorem is essentially derived from Cauchy formula. Cauchy formula in complex analysis is a result of Green theorem and Cauchy-Riemann equation. I notice that for path integral in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the analyticity of the complex function is analogous to vector field being conservative (curl=0 is like Cauchy-Riemann equation given it is a iff condition given continuity of partial derivatives). Is there an analogous version of Residue theorem in Euclidea space (2D in particular) to evaluate path integral? For example, vector field such as $(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$ has a "pole" at $(0,0)$ and thus the path integral of a unit circle around 0 gives $2\pi$, instead of 0. Is it possible to generalize this to a formula?

Comment: NB that $\operatorname{curl} {\bf F} = 0$ is not the same as ${\bf F}$ being conservative---indeed, the path integral you mention shows that $\bf F$ is not conservative.

Comment: The property of being complex-analytic is stronger than a vector field being irrotational (that is, satisfying $\operatorname{curl} {\bf F} = 0$) in a sense that can be made precise: Given a complex-analytic function $g(x, y) = u(x, y) + i v(x, y)$, identify $\Bbb C \leftrightarrow \Bbb R^2$ and define the vector field ${\bf F}(u, -v)$. Then, the Cauchy-Riemann equation $u_y = -v_x$ is exactly the statement that $\operatorname{curl} {\bf F} = 0$. The remaining equation, $u_x = v_y,$ is an additional condition---$\operatorname{div} {\bf F} = 0$---that is, that $\bf F$ is *incompressible*.